# Clevertap web push not working on Firefox and Chrome 71

Tags: javascript, web-push, clevertap

I've worked with web push on before with firebase and it worked fine on every platforms, as per the docs it says, ["currently supported for Chrome version 50 for Desktop and Android"](https://developer.clevertap.com/docs/web#section-web-push) but after that I read a community discussion for the same, [Web Push Notification for Safari and Firefox not working](https://community.clevertap.com/t/web-push-notification-for-safari-and-firefox-not-working/371). In which it was said that the next version would contain that. So did that happened or not?

Next problem is that I tried notifications on Chrome 71 (on windows) but the user didn't got registered for desktop notifications on clevertap console, I correctly did process of registering the service worker and other necessities, from a website that has already been tested with other chrome versions.

Answer (score 1):

As of now Web push notifications in CleverTap are only supported on Chrome and not on Safari or Firefox. It will be picked up in the future but isn't prioritised for now.

Web push on Chrome v71 on Windows should work as expected. Could you please write to support@clevertap.com with details of your website where you've configured, the support team will help you out with the configuration.